# Git ignore implementation in C#

Tags: git

How can I properly implement the use of git ignore to not commit .json files to my repository?

I tried watching a youtube video for help, but after following his tips my json file is still being uploaded.

Comment: What does the respective entry in your .gitignore file look like and where did you put that file?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/VisualStudio.gitignore
Here is a general .gitignore file.
Use this in your main directory containing the solution, and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ignore you must place the `.gitignore` at top-level directory of your `.git` repository.

Here is a link to [github](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/VisualStudio.gitignore) which upkeep the `.gitignore` for C#. Of course you can edit it as you like but the most common things are already done for you.

The general way of updating `.gitignore` is simple. Add `*.anyextension` to ignore any file that is with that extension. This can get a lot more complex if you want to ignore more complex things from that file but like I said most of them are done for you already.

E.G

```
MyGitRepoFoder -> (contents) .git(hidden) you want to place the .gitignore here
```

Use this its what I use for every C# project, I have also added to ignore  anything with `JSON` extension

```
## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.

# Visual Studio (>=2015) project-specific, machine local files
.vs/

# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.sln.docstates
*.userprefs

# ignore Xamarin.Android Resource.Designer.cs files
**/*.Droid/**/[Rr]esource.[Dd]esigner.cs
**/*.Android/**/[Rr]esource.[Dd]esigner.cs
**/Android/**/[Rr]esource.[Dd]esigner.cs
**/Droid/**/[Rr]esource.[Dd]esigner.cs

# Xamarin Components
Components/

# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
x64/
build/
bld/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/

# MSTest test Results
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*/
[Bb]uild[Ll]og.*

#NUNIT
*.VisualState.xml
TestResult.xml

# Build Results of an ATL Project
[Dd]ebugPS/
[Rr]eleasePS/
dlldata.c

*_i.c
*_p.c
*_i.h
*.ilk
*.meta
*.obj
*.pch
*.pdb
*.pgc
*.pgd
*.rsp
*.sbr
*.tlb
*.tli
*.tlh
*.tmp
*.tmp_proj
*.log
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
.builds
*.pidb
*.svclog
*.scc

# Chutzpah Test files
_Chutzpah*

# Visual C++ cache files
ipch/
*.aps
*.ncb
*.opensdf
*.sdf
*.cachefile

# Visual Studio profiler
*.psess
*.vsp
*.vspx

# TFS 2012 Local Workspace
$tf/

# Guidance Automation Toolkit
*.gpState

# ReSharper is a .NET coding add-in
_ReSharper*/
*.[Rr]e[Ss]harper
*.DotSettings.user

# JustCode is a .NET coding addin-in
.JustCode

# TeamCity is a build add-in
_TeamCity*

# DotCover is a Code Coverage Tool
*.dotCover

# NCrunch
*.ncrunch*
_NCrunch_*
.*crunch*.local.xml

# MightyMoose
*.mm.*
AutoTest.Net/

# Web workbench (sass)
.sass-cache/

# Installshield output folder
[Ee]xpress/

# DocProject is a documentation generator add-in
DocProject/buildhelp/
DocProject/Help/*.HxT
DocProject/Help/*.HxC
DocProject/Help/*.hhc
DocProject/Help/*.hhk
DocProject/Help/*.hhp
DocProject/Help/Html2
DocProject/Help/html

# Click-Once directory
publish/

# Publish Web Output
*.[Pp]ublish.xml
*.azurePubxml

# NuGet Packages Directory
packages/
*.nuget.targets
*.lock.json
*.nuget.props

## TODO: If the tool you use requires repositories.config uncomment the next line
#!packages/repositories.config

# Enable "build/" folder in the NuGet Packages folder since NuGet packages use it for MSBuild targets
# This line needs to be after the ignore of the build folder (and the packages folder if the line above has been uncommented)
!packages/build/

# Windows Azure Build Output
csx/
*.build.csdef

# Windows Store app package directory
AppPackages/

# Others
sql/
*.Cache
ClientBin/
[Ss]tyle[Cc]op.*
~$*
*~
*.dbmdl
*.dbproj.schemaview
*.pfx
*.publishsettings
node_modules/
.DS_Store
*.bak

# RIA/Silverlight projects
Generated_Code/

# Backup & report files from converting an old project file to a newer
# Visual Studio version. Backup files are not needed, because we have git ;-)
_UpgradeReport_Files/
Backup*/
UpgradeLog*.XML
UpgradeLog*.htm

# SQL Server files
*.mdf
*.ldf

# Business Intelligence projects
*.rdl.data
*.bim.layout
*.bim_*.settings

# Microsoft Fakes
FakesAssemblies/

.vscode/settings.json

#Ignore APK
*.apk

#Ignore JSON
*.json
```

Comment: "I have also added to ignore anything with JSON extension"  might want to add... which you can find, if you scroll to the bottom of the code snippet

Answer (score 1):

In order to ignore all files of a certain type, use a wildcard (`*`) followed by the file extension.

The following will ignore all JSON files within your project

```
*.json
```

Sidenote: your `.gitignore` needs to be located in the top-level directory. In other words, same directory as the solution file is located.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that updating of `.gitignore` is not enough in your case. You need to stop tracking json files.
Point is, that once file has being tracked by git, and then you ignore it - anyway git does not remove it. Because it stops tracking *changes* of that file, but not file itself.

So, first add `*.json` to `.gitignore`.

And then stop tracking any json files, which have been already added to git previously (*file* is file name for the command below):

```
git rm --cached <file>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I assume you committed the json file before adding it into `.gitignore`. So, `Git` woon't automatically ignore it.

To address this issue, you need to remove the file from the staging area. However, I suppose that you may not wish to remove it from your working directory entirely.

To solely remove the file from the staging area, follow these steps:

1. Remove file from the staging area.

```
git rm --cached -r <fileName>
```

2. Run `git status` to check what happened.
3. You're gonna see that a message **deleted: filename.**, which means everything is okay now.

P.S. Please note that this explanation assumes that the JSON file has already been added to the `.gitignore` file. Otherwise, after the above steps, you must add the file to `.gitignore`.